# Gradle only downloads pom from mavenCentral - Android

Tags: android, gradle, maven-central

I have successfully deployed an AAR artifact to mavenCentral using Sonatype's OSS Nexus but when i reference it on another project gradle is only downloading the pom and it's respective ASC file to ~/.gradle/cache.

This is my build.gradle http://pastie.org/private/zaxa13hsd52e4elfpnne4w
This is the build.gradle for the library https://github.com/Machinarius/PreferenceFragment-Compat/blob/master/build.gradle

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you show (or link to) the published POM and the `dependencies` block of the other project?

Comment: Link for the published artifact: http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|com.github.machinarius|preferencefragment|0.1|aar.asc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `aar.asc` packaging is coming from this section in your gradle configuration:

```
configurations {
  archives {
    extendsFrom configurations.default
  }
}
```

Remove those lines from your build.gradle file and deploy again. You should see the packaging be `aar` now.

Comment: I wound up doing something like this to avoid the `@aar` workaround

Comment: I have a [very similar problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21942727/gradle-only-downloads-aar-asc-from-maven-central) - can you tell how I can test this locally?

Answer (score 1):

The value for the POM's `packaging` element (`aar.asc`) looks wrong. You should nevertheless be able to fetch the artifact with something like `dependencies { compile 'com.github.machinarius:preferencefragment:0.1@aar' }`. With this "artifact only" notation, you won't get transitive dependencies, but you can always declare those yourself.

Comment: Seems like the signing step changed the packaging, i will research into that.