# Gradle only downloads .aar.asc from Maven Central

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-library, maven-central

I freshly deployed an Android library named [TypedPreferences](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/TypedPreferences). I used it in another Android project for some days. Suddenly, it stopped working - **dependencies cannot be found** any longer. I noticed that Gradle only downloads one file when I clean the project:

```
Download http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/info/metadude/android/typed-preferences/ \
  1.0.0/typed-preferences-1.0.0.aar.asc
```

These are build files of my pet project:

`build.gradle`:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration 
// options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "${System.env.HOME}/.m2/repository"
        }
        maven {
            url "https://github.com/novoda/public-mvn-repo/raw/master/releases"
        }
    }
}
```

`app/build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'idea'

idea {
    module {
        downloadJavadoc = true
        downloadSources = true
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.3.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.novoda:sqliteprovider-core:1.0.+'
    compile 'com.androidmapsextensions:android-maps-extensions:2.1.+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.+'
    compile 'info.metadude.android:typed-preferences:1.0.0'
}
```

As you can see, I also enable Gradle to look into my local Maven cache here:

```
maven {
    url "${System.env.HOME}/.m2/repository"
}
```

I deleted the relevant folders to avoid Gradle loading stuff from there.

There might be a misconfiguration in the `build.gradle` files of the library - please find them here:

- [Library files](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/TypedPreferences)

Please tell me also whether I can test your fix locally without deploying to Maven Central.

Comment: "Suddenly stopped working" is strange. Are you sure the remaining files aren't cached already? (`gradle clean` won't clean the dependency cache.) The first thing to try in such a case is to run with `--refresh-dependencies`. Which Gradle version are you using? The local Maven repo should only be declared if the Gradle build needs to consume the output of a local Maven build (there are no other benefits, only drawbacks). And if it's declared, it should be `mavenLocal()`.

Comment: The Gradle wrapper I use defines v.1.10. I cleaned the caches (Maven and Gradle) manually by removing the directory of the library. `gradle --refresh-dependencies` downloads the `.pom` and the `.aar.asc`. Still dependencies cannot be found.

Comment: Try to remove the Maven local declaration, and try to run with `--info` or `--debug`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the `packaging` element of the published POM has the wrong value. It should be `aar`, not `aar.asc`.

Comment: As far as I understand the POM is generated from what I defined in the [build.gradle](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/TypedPreferences/blob/master/Library/build.gradle). Can you spot what is wrong there?

Comment: `packaging "aar", "jar"` looks suspicious, because there can only be one value for packaging. I don't know where the `aar.asc` comes from.

Comment: That doesn't mean it's right. Crouton's build script has `packaging "jar", "aar"` (i.e. the reverse order). Perhaps the first value wins, and `jar` is the default packaging type for a POM. This would explain why its published POM doesn't have a `packaging` element.

Comment: The [Crouton library specifies both types](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton/blob/master/library/build.gradle#L108) as well. I will try to adapt the `jar` task which is setup there.

Comment: As I said, it specifies them in a different order, which may make a difference in practice. Nevertheless, specifying two types is definitely wrong.

Comment: I changed the `package` settings and deployed a new version. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you always can force the type of artifact to download. Just add dependency like:

```
compile "group:artifact:version@type"
```

And in your case it will be

```
compile "info.metadude.android:typed-preferences:1.0.0@aar"
```

That's it.